# Calculate optimized distance between a source and destination with multiple waypoints in between in c#

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-api

I have a fixed source and a destination. But i have multiple waypoints in between. I have to calculate the distance of optimized route between the source and destination. 
I have to do it in c#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?csw=1) for that purpose:

> The Google Directions API is a service that calculates directions
>   between locations using an HTTP request

**Using Waypoints in Routes**

> When calculating routes using the Directions API, you may also specify
>   waypoints for driving, walking or bicycling directions.
>
> For example, the following URL initiates a Directions request for a
>   route between Boston, MA and Concord, MA with stopovers in Charlestown
>   and Lexington, in that order:
>
> ```
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&key=API_KEY
> ```

**How to consume  [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?csw=1) in .Net**

The following example demonstrates how to construct Directions request:

```
public class DirectionsClient
{
    public static JObject CalcRoute(string origin,string destination,string[] waypoints)
    {
        var requestUrl = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin={0}&destination={1}&waypoints={2}", origin, destination, string.Join("|",waypoints));
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var result = client.DownloadString(requestUrl);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(result);
            //ensure directions response contains a valid result
            if ((string) data["status"] != "OK")
            throw new Exception("Invalid request");
            return data;
        }   
    }
}
```

**Example**

When the Directions API returns results, it places them within a (JSON) routes array.

The example shows how to print [Legs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?csw=1#Legs) info:

```
var data = DirectionsClient.CalcRoute("Boston,MA", "Concord,MA", new[] { "Charlestown,MA", "Lexington,MA"});

foreach (var route in data["routes"])
{
    foreach (var leg in route["legs"])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start: {0} End {1}", leg["start_address"], leg["end_address"]);
    }   
 }
```

**Update**

Regarding the format of request:

> Directions may specify origins, destinations and waypoints either as
>   text strings (e.g. "Chicago, IL" or "Darwin, NT, Australia") or as
>   **latitude/longitude coordinates**.

Regarding route optimization:

> By default, the Directions service calculates a route through the
>   provided waypoints in their given order. Optionally, you may pass
>   optimize:true as the first argument within the waypoints parameter to
>   allow the Directions service to optimize the provided route by
>   rearranging the waypoints in a more efficient order. (This
>   optimization is an application of the Travelling Salesman Problem.)
>
> If you instruct the Directions service to optimize the order of its
>   waypoints, their order will be returned in the waypoint_order field
>   within the routes object. The waypoint_order field returns values
>   which are zero-based.
>
> The following example calculates a road trip route from Adelaide,
>   South Australia to each of South Australia's main wine regions using
>   route optimization.
>
> ```
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&key=API_KEY
> ```
>
> Inspection of the calculated route will indicate that the route is
>   calculated using the following waypoint order:
>
> ```
> "waypoint_order": [ 1, 0, 2, 3 ]
> ```

Comment: Cant i do it by giving latitude and longitude instead of giving address. And i have to find out the address, instead of ordering of waypoints.

Comment: In this example if u swap your waypoints then also shows the same path. I need the optimized route.

Comment: Have you even checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?csw=1)?  The answer has been updated

Comment: Just tell me this, given 2 pair of latlng, how can i find driving distance between them in C#. The remaining part i can do it using my own algorithm.